# Seeking Guidance for Reading Aristotle's Metaphysics

Tags: metaphysics, aristotle, ancient-philosophy

I've recently embarked on a journey to explore Aristotle's Metaphysics, but I must admit, I'm finding it quite challenging to grasp. As a newcomer to Aristotle's works, I wonder if there's a guide or companion text that could assist me in comprehending the intricate concepts presented in Metaphysics.

Since this is my first attempt at reading Aristotle, would it be advisable to start with another one of his works before delving into the complexities of Metaphysics? If so, any recommendations on where to begin would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe useful Vasilis Politis, [Routledge Philosophy Guidebook to Aristotle and the Metaphysics (2004)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Routledge_Philosophy_Guidebook_to_Aristo/ab07GTXZnAIC)

Comment: You should not feel too bad. The book is a collection of notes with controversial dating and relationships to each other assembled by editors long after Aristotle's death and then copied, translated and recopied by people who did not always understand the text. Getting a map before diving in is a good idea. [SEP's article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-metaphysics/) is a good brief intro, [Lear's companion](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Aristotle/hSAGlzPLq7gC?hl=en) comes with good reviews, there is also Halper's concise Reader's Guide.